# Different table cell color for MySQL data

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I wanted to change the background color of the table cell for different MySQL data. My situation is when the user input their weight and height, it will calculate their Body Mass Index (BMI) as well as output the BMI categories. Something like this:

[image: BMItable]

Now how do I change the table cell color for BMI categories where "underweight" will be white, "Normal Weight" is yellow and "Overweight" is orange? I've tried the following but doesn't work.

This is what I have in my PHP code:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Name</th> //etc.
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>No records found.</td></tr>";

else {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
 //some more codes for weight, height, BMI
 echo "<td class='<?php $tdClass; ?>'>" . $row['Health_Measure'] . "</td>";
 }
}
echo "</table>";

if ($row['Health_Measure'] == "Underweight") 
        $tdClass = 'underweight';

else if ($row['Health_Measure'] == "Normal Weight") 
    $tdClass = 'normalweight';

else if ($row['Health_Measure'] == "Overweight") 
    $tdClass = 'overweight';
```

CSS:

```
.underweight {
    background-color:white;
}
.normalweight {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.overweight {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: Does it generate the correct HTML? Nothing at all? Something, but not what it's supposed to?

Comment: The class is not applied to the cell?

Comment: there was no error and the table output just as it is in the picture. It seems like it's not applying the tdClass

Answer (score 3):

Your code to assign the $tdClass variable is after the loop that uses the $tdClass variable, so the td tags won't have the right classes. Change it to this...

```
    echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Name</th> //etc.
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>No records found.</td></tr>";

else {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
    if ($row['Health_Measure'] == "Underweight") 
        $tdClass = 'underweight';

else if ($row['Health_Measure'] == "Normal Weight") 
    $tdClass = 'normalweight';

else if ($row['Health_Measure'] == "Overweight") 
    $tdClass = 'overweight';

 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
 //some more codes for weight, height, BMI
 echo "<td class='<?php $tdClass; ?>'>" . $row['Health_Measure'] . "</td></tr>";
 }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I see you were missing a closing tr tag which I've added to my answer. That's probably not the issue though. I would statically apply the class names to the td tags and see if that works... to help narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your code to determine the CSS class for the TD inside the loop where you output the table rows.